# Easy way to "organize"/"render"/"generate" HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm a relative newbie to web development.  I know my HTML and CSS, and am getting involved with Ruby on Rails for some other projects, which has been daunting but very rewarding.

Basically I'm wondering if there's a language/backbone/program/solution to eliminate the copypasta trivialities of HTML, with some caveats.  Currently my website is hosted on a school server and unfortunately can't use Rails.  Being a newbie I also don't really know what other technologies are available to me (or even what those technologies might be).  I'm essentially looking for a way to auto-insert all of my header/sidebar/footer/menu information, and when those need to be updated, the rest of the pages get updated.  Right now, I have a sidebar that is a tree of all of the pages on my website.  When I add a page, not only do I need to update the sidebar, I have to update it for every page in my domain.  This is really inefficient and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I imagine this is a pretty widespread problem, but searching Google turns up too many irrelevant links (design template websites, tutorials, etc.).  I'd appreciate any help.

Oh, and I've heard of HAML as a way to render HTML; how would it be used in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

Old as time. Supported in most hosting situations. Often forgotten in favour of hugely overcomplicated templating systems. SSI still has a place.

Comment: Thanks Oli, this seems like the simplest solution (my site is very small).  I have a problem with relative paths, though.  It's best described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016917/should-i-use-relative-path-for-pages-within-the-site-or-it-doesnt-matter (the templating issue).  Is there an easy way around this?  I've tried using "link rel="/yaddayaddayadda" but that doesn't seem to work locally, which is a bummer.  Or is it best practice to have _all_ of the .html files in the root folder...?  Mine are within subfolders. Edit:Maybe create multiple includes, one per subfolder depth?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're talking about. If you're doing `<link>` elements in the header (as your code suggests), you need to use `href` to point to the file. If you're talking about `<!--#include -->`, I suggest you use virtual paths. These are "root-relative" to your URL so ` <!--#include virtual="/inc/sidebar.html"-->` would always pull in the same file. The same applies for resource `<link>`s actually, root-relative will save you problems down the line.

Comment: In short, all your references to other files, be they a `<!--#include-->`, `<a>` or `<link>`,  should probably use the whole root-relative path. There are exceptions where it's desirable not to do this but if you're having problems, now isn't one of those times.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've set up XAMPP and now have SSI working, and now my root-relative paths are all set up.  The problem was that I was just trying to access my pages from my local directory structure on my PC, and that didn't like SSI.

Answer (score 1):

You use a template language.

Most often this will be processed on the server, but there are offline solutions which you run though a utility to generate complete HTML documents for uploading.

I'm rather fond of [Template-Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) which I usually use server side with [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) but it also very usable before you involve a web server using [the ttree utility](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html).

Answer (score 1):

...........[Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Working_with_WordPress#Site_Development)?

Comment: Downvote if you will, I stand by my answer based on his criteria.

Comment: +1 - I wholeheartedly agree that recommending a CMS is the right thing to do. Be it Drupal (that's what I recommended), Joomla, EZpublish, Wordpress or other, it should give him the possibilities to overcome the difficulties he describes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Drupal. The tree structure of a menu is an inbuilt function and you basically can forget about it at all. And inserting whatever you want in specified areas (footer, header, whatever's defined in a template). It relies on PHP and MySQL - that stuff can be used on almost any server. And it has a moderate learning curve, so you should be able to start doing magic in little time.